# Are there any good publicly accessible wisdom of crowd data sets?

Tags: data-mining, dataset

I am looking for publicly accessible data sets to explore some wisdom of the crowd ideas.

An ideal data set would contain predictions from a number of individuals (who were not collaborating with each other, or at least only minimally) on events with known outcomes.

Predictions in terms of probability of events occurring (e.g., 80% chance of depression in the US in 20xx), binary-valued predictions (e.g., there will be a depression in the US in 20xx), or real values of quantities (e.g., average number of goals per match in World Cup 2014 is 2.75) are all okay. These predictions need to be paired with their corresponding objective ground truth, so that I can evaluate how different methods of aggregating data can produce estimates that are the closest to the ground truth.

Any domain are okay. This includes but not limited to politics, economy, business, military, sports.

Missing data (some predictors did not make predictions for all questions) are okay.

I'd like the data to be readily downloadable (e.g., I don't want to write code to scrap a web site).

Answer (score 1):

Prediction markets such as [IEM](http://tippie.uiowa.edu/iem/), [Tradesports](http://tradesports.com/) (and its defunct parent [InTrade](https://www.intrade.com/v4/home/)), [Inkling](http://home.inklingmarkets.com/), and [iPredict](https://www.ipredict.co.nz/) might be good places to start. Some price histories are available for IEM [here](https://iemweb.biz.uiowa.edu/WebEx/marketoverview.cfm).

Comment: Of all the sites you have listed, I don't see any one that provides downloadable data. Most of them don't even let you see historical data. The most useful of them would be IEM, but even they only give you the market price history. Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

The [Netflix Dataset](http://www.lifecrunch.biz/archives/207) is good, as is the [Jester data](http://www.ieor.berkeley.edu/~goldberg/jester-data/) from UC Berkeley. Google "collaborative filtering dataset" and there's a ton of them in all kinds of fields.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear (I have clarified this in the question now), I'd like to the data to be predictions/estimates about certain quantities with precise quantities that are knowable. Collaborating filter data sets generally represent each judge's own preferences and don't corresponding to objective ground truths, either individually or in aggregate.